# Xserver/Xorg is broken, fails to load default video configuration

Tags: xorg, video, xserver

When I started my computer today after editing the `/etc/init.d/gdm` file, the `xserver`, for lack of better words, "messed up" and failed to load the default video configuration. How can I fix this?

I realise my question may seem uneducated and the wording may be wrong, but that was the file I used `nano` to edit and that was what caused the `xserver` to break.

This is not a duplicate of any other question, I checked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into recovery mode.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Get a user or root shell, and run :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm
```

and reboot.